# How to display a cursor on top of an image using HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and JavaScript and I have an assignment that I can't solve. I have displayed an image on HTML using 'map' and created with clickable 'areas'.
Now, I would like to display the image of a cursor, like the Google Maps cursor for example, at the center of my area, when the mouse is in the area.

I have tried the "document.getElementById" function but it replaces my image instead of overlaying it to my background image.

I have searched an answer to this problem on the Internet but I have only found CSS and jQuery solutions, and since I don't understand those codes, I can't use them.
Here is my code :

```
 <img src="image.png" border="0" class="map" usemap="#mymap" id="picture"/>

<map name="mymap">

    <area shape="rect"
        coords="419,451,453,477"
        title="This is area 1"
        href="#"            
        onmouseover="document.getElementById('picture').src='image2.png';"
        onmouseout="document.getElementById('picture').src='image.png';"
        />

</map>
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I doubt you're gonna get an answer without css.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the src of the original image, so it's something to expect that the image is replaced.

Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/C5qPZ/2/

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative;">
<img src="http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/multimedia/archive/00342/114240651_cat_342943c.jpg" border="0" class="map" usemap="#mymap" id="picture"/>
<img src="http://www.mycatspace.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/adopting-a-cat.jpg" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:0; top:0" id="picture2"/>

<map name="mymap">

    <area shape="rect"
        coords="0,100,100,150"
        title="This is area 1"
        href="#"            
       onmouseover="document.getElementById('picture2').style.display = 'block';"
        />    
</map>
```

CSS is hard-coded in my example. I know you don't want CSS, but some it's needed if you want to show the image over the first one.

If the only reason for not using it is that you don't really understand it (as you state), you are better off trying to learn it (it's not that difficult) instead of reverting to weird solutions.

Comment: "it replaces my image instead of overlaying it to my background image." - OP wants to show a picture on hover, not to change the default cursor style..